# How to use SQL Server trigger to insert data into table_2(Log)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create a trigger when I am updating table, I want `table_2` to update the `transaction_id` from table `transactions`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMnb1.png)

Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[after_update]
ON [dbo].[transactions]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_2 (detail, transaction_id)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), (SELECT transaction_id 
                        FROM transactions 
                        WHERE transaction_id = 3))
END
```

Table: table_2 (Log)

```
id  detail                 transaction_id
------------------------------------------
20  Jan 16 2021  1:42AM    NULL
```

Table: transaction:

```
id  request_original    transaction_id
------------------------------------------
1   NULL                842202611500000001
2   NULL                842202621200000001
3   1                   842202621200000002
4   NULL                842202621200000003
5   NULL                842202621700000001
6   NULL                842202621700000002
```

Comment: Show us ***YOUR*** efforts so far! What have you tried - where are you stuck? Please post the code here - as properly formatted text (not screenshot)

Comment: You need to use `inserted` psuedo-table in the trigger, don't forget to matche it against `deleted` table to check what is actually changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this logic:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (detail, transaction_id)
    SELECT GETDATE(), transaction_id
    FROM inserted;
```

I'm not sure what `where transaction_id = 3`.  However, a SQL Server trigger that does not refer to `inserted` or `deleted` is probably broken -- and one that assumes that they have only one row is *definitely* broken.

Comment: "where transaction_id = 3" i am hard code because i am not how to trigger insert transaction_id from table:transaction  to transaction_id  from table:table_2